# Allow changing the properties of a mutable controller in a thread safe way

Tags: c#, thread-safety, immutability

I have a (control engineering) controller. These controllers usually need several parameters to do their thing, and in my application it is desirable that these parameters can be changed while the controller is running - in a thread safe and well defined manner.

I came up with this design (extremely simplified):

```
// This is the class that the user instanciates.
public class Controller
{
    public ControllerInfo Info { get; set; }

    public void Start() { ... }
    public void Stop() { ... }

    private ControllerBody body = new ControllerBody();

    private void ControllerThreadProc()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var elapsedTime_ms = ...;
            var currentInfo = this.Info;
            // the actual calculation is done in another class
            this.body.SingleStep(currentInfo, elapsedTime_ms);
            Thread.Sleep(currentInfo.SampleTime_ms);
        }
    }
}

// This exists as a separate class so it is possible to test the
// mathematical model without having to do it in real-time.
public class ControllerBody
{
    public void SingleStep(ControllerInfo info, long elapsedTime_ms)
    {
        var referenceValue = info.ReferenceValueGetter();
        var calculationResult = math;
        info.ControlValueSetter(calculationResult);
    }
}

// Immutable class that contains all the info necessary to do stuff.
public class ControllerInfo
{
    public Func<double> ReferenceValueGetter { get; private set; }
    public Action<double> ControlValueSetter { get; private set; }
    public int SampleTime_ms { get; private set; }
    public double SomeConstant { get; private set; }
    public double OtherConstant { get; private set; }
    ...

    public ControllerInfo(/* 1 argument per property :( */) { /* many assignments */ }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var controller = new Controller();
controller.Info = new ControllerInfo(/* values */);
controller.Start();
// later:
controller.Info = new ControllerInfo(/* new values */);
// Application is done:
controller.Stop();
```

Again, it should be possible to change the controller while it is running. Therefore I gave `Controller` a publicly settable `ControllerInfo`.

However, if the user decides to change the values of `SomeConstant` **and** `OtherConstant` in this example, it must be guaranteed that no calculation step is executed where only *one* of these are changed. In other words, changing a bunch of parameters must be an atomic operation. That's why `ControllerInfo` is not mutable.

I have identified 2 downsides to this architecture:

1. If I add another mathematical constant to `ControllerInfo`, I have to add (1) a property, (2) a parameter to the constructor (can be forgotten even if (1) has been done!), and (3) an assigment inside the constructor (can be forgotten even if (1) and (2) have been done!).
2. If the user wants to change a parameter while the controller is running, they must make another tedious constructor call, passing in values that have changed, as well as values that haven't changed.

To get around the usability problem, I considered introducing a `ControllerInfoFactory` class, which is basically a mutable copy of `ControllerInfo`:

```
public class ControllerInfoFactory
{
    public (SamePropertiesAsControllerInfo) { get; set; }

    public ControllerInfo CreateControllerInfo()
    {
        return new ControllerInfo(/* pass all parameters from this */);
    }
}
```

However, that makes the first problem even worse: For each property, I now also have to add the property to `ControllerInfoFactory`. Luckily, this time it's not possible to forget updating the `CreateControllerInfo` method as long as the `ControllerInfo` constructor has already been updated.

Now to code review:

1. Does this design make sense? Is the usability OK?
2. Can the large amount of repetitive code per property be reduced?

Comment: Why is this tagged 'Java'? It appears to be exclusively C# code. From what I understand, the threading mechanisms and classes in the two languages are rather different.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Because I could think of no difference between the languages that is relevant to this question. I chose to settle for the C# syntax for the code samples simply because the property notation seemed more concise. I could have just used a UML class diagram instead.

Comment: Removed Java tag, because a logical answer for a Java question of this sort would be to use java.util.concurrent.* - and there's no Java code to review

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to create ControllerInfo with mutable properties and a Clone method which would return a copy of the instance.

Then on the ControllerInfo Info set, simply call the Clone method and set _info to the clone of the object passed in.

```
private ControllerInfo _info;

public Info
{
   get { return _info; }
   set { _info = value.Clone(); }
}
```

To be clearer you can do away with Info as a property and instead code a method

```
public Controller SetInfo(ControllerInfo info)
{
     _info = info.Clone(); 
     return this;
}
```

Doing away with "get" semantics for Info, is a good idea, as you do not want the interface to suggest that a get followed by mutating the Info object would reflect the changes in the Controller.

Comment: BTW, you can implement `Clone()` using [`MemberwiseClone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone), which would avoid any repetition.